# mysql - want to create error

Tags: php, mysql

im new at programing and php, and i want to create an error on my registration system that when the user creates an account with the same username already existing in the database it says something like this: "Username already in use" and then if it isnt an existing username it says "Registation Complete"

I tried this code:

```
<?
require ("conect.php");

$user = $_POST['user'];

$pass = $_POST['password'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$email_check = $_POST['email_check'];


$register = mysql_fetch_array; 




if($user = $register[user]) {
echo"Username already in use";
}
else
{

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registration (user, password, email)
        VALUES('$_POST[user]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]')");

    echo "The account $user was successfully created.";

}

?>
```

But it didnt work, can someone help please

Comment: `$register = mysql_fetch_array; ` what do you think this does ?

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server+site pwn3d.

Comment: you need to look up a PHP tutorial on how to select data. you've got the right idea but the wrong syntax here - you want to select a minimal amount of data from your table where username = posted username, if it returns, it exists, if not, insert (your insert query is fine, but it's a major security risk - you need to escape posted variables like that with `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `htmlentities` etc)

Comment: The question title suggests that you intend to create an error.

Comment: This is not even close. Find a good tutorial and follow that, then try again. Don't use `mysql_*` - the functions are deprecated. Go for `mysqli` or `PDO`. [Here's a start](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Comment: Please don't use short open tags `<? ?>` because it's a **pain** if you moved to an environment where it's disabled by default. Always check if the variables are set. And as stated don't use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: I dont want to create any super safe and professional website (im still new at programing and php), i am just making some php tests on a free host, and i just want to know if there is anyway do to what i want with the functions i wrote. Anyway, thanks for the tips, i surely will follow your tips for "real" websites.

Answer (score 3):

1. As pointed out by the other users, you should be using prepared statements through PDO (or mysqli, but I definitely prefer PDO)
2. You're storing the POSTS in variables, but then in the database query you are just using the $_POST variable again?
3. I'm not sure what your doing with the `$register = mysql_fetch_array` part, but to get the desired functionality you should use a select query to count the number of users using the username.
4. You're not using any secure hash format to store the password. I switched it to use password_hash().

Try something like this (I haven't tested the code yet though, so there might be errors):

```
<?php

    //Put all POSTS in variables
    $user                 = $_POST['user'];
    $pass                 = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $email                = $_POST['email'];
    $email_check          = $_POST['email_check'];

    //Database config- probably should store in a separate file
    $database_host        = "";
    $database_name        = "";
    $database_user        = "";
    $database_password    = "";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$database_host;dbname=$database_name",$database_user,$database_password);

    //Find out if the username is taken.
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `registration` WHERE user = :user"; 
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $q->execute(array(':user' => $user)); 
    $number_of_rows = $q->fetchColumn();

    //Clear $sql and $q so you can use them again
    $sql = NULL;
    $q   = NULL;

    if ($number_of_rows > 1) {

        //Username already taken
        echo "Username already taken";

    } 
    else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO registration (user,password,email) VALUES (:user,:password,:email)";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':user'=>$user, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));

        echo "The account " . $user . " was successfully created";

    }
?>
```

Comment: `password_hash()` only appeared with PHP 5.5 which isn't available on a lot of hosting servers yet.

Answer (score 1):

You really, really need to read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). The method you are using is very old, incredibly insecure, and generally a bad-practice by today's standards.

Your code isn't even worth fixing for these reasons, it should be re-written using prepared statements.

Comment: Well im not trying to create a safe website, in fact, i am using a free host where im doing tests about php. But thanks for the help anyway, and i'll check on that link